# Displaying the Name of a Table on an Template

Tags: python, django

I have a model/table, `WeekOne` with various fields. It also has a unicode field:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Week One'
```

`WeekOne` is a foreign key of `user`, defined using the variable `weekOne.` Thinking I could leverage the unicode field in a template, I tried to display the name using the following code:

```
{{ user.weekOne }}
```

Nothing showed up. It's not an issue of my models functioning properly, I access other fields in model/weekOne throughout the template without issue. What's the best way to display the name of a table? Do I need to create a "Name" field? That seems like kind of a waste, since every user would have a WeekOne table with the redundant "Name" field.

Here is the model of UserProfile, which is what the user variable references:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    weekOne = models.OneToOneField(WeekOne)
```

When I do something like user.weekOne.items (items is a field in weekOne), it shows up on the template.

Comment: This is not clear. What is `user` here - the normal Django user? What is the relationship between user and WeekOne?

Comment: Show us your model(s). I think you confused couple of things here.

Comment: You does not refer to the table information, you refer to the value of weekOne field.

Comment: The weekOne field is a one to one reference to another table with fields. What I want to do is display a name for that table. I've updated with the model for UserProfile at the end. WeekOne is a big model, but it's not its fields I'm interested in. I just want to be able to display a name for it, preferably without having to create a "Name" field.

Comment: So are you sure that `user` in your template is an instance of `UserProfile` rather than - as would make more sense - `User`?

Comment: For some strange reason it is referencing UserProfile, even though I've done nothing to change the user variable. I still don't fully understand that variable in terms of templates/forms. However, it turns out that {{ user.weekOne }} works (matter of mixing up the capitalization for the most part).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{{ user.userprofile.weekOne }}
```

PS: Don't refer to a Model as Table. Model is a class. It is used to talk to the database table. Table name and Model name can be different.